# How to add line break between inputText Fields in panelgrid

Tags: visualforce, line-break, panelgrid

I have the following visualforce code:

```
<apex:page id="communitiesSelfRegPage" showHeader="true" 
standardStylesheets="true" controller="CommunitiesSelfRegController" title=" 
{!$Label.site.user_registration}">
<apex:define name="body">   
<style>
  .valueCol input { display: inline-block; width: 100% }
</style>

<center>      
<apex:form id="theForm" forceSSL="true">
    <div style="height:530px">
    <!--<apex:pageBlock>-->
                <apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
                <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:2em;"> 
                  <apex:outputLabel value="First Name" for="firstName"/>
                  <apex:inputText required="true" id="firstName" value="{!firstName}" label="First Name"/>


                  <apex:outputLabel value="Last Name" for="lastName"/>
                  <apex:inputText required="true" id="lastName" value="{!lastName}" label="Last Name"/>


                  <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.community_nickname}" for="communityNickname"/>
                  <apex:inputText required="true" id="communityNickname" value="{!communityNickname}" label="{!$Label.site.community_nickname}"/>



                  <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.email}" for="email"/>
                  <apex:inputText required="true" id="email" value="{!email}" label="{!$Label.site.email}"/>



                  <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.password}" for="password"/>
                  <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}"/>



                  <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.confirm_password}" for="confirmPassword"/>
                  <apex:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" value="{!confirmPassword}"/>

                  <br></br>

                  <apex:outputText value=""/>
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!registerUser}" value="{!$Label.site.submit}" id="submit"/>
                </apex:panelGrid> 
              <br/>
     </div>
    <!--</apex:pageBlock> -->
 </apex:form>
 </center>

   <br/>
  </apex:define>
```

The output of the code is as follows:
[image]

How do I add line break after each input field such that the fields cover up the whole page and look more aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the cellpadding attribute in apex:panelgrid tag

```
    <apex:panelGrid cellpadding="10px" columns="2" width="100%">
        <apex:outputLabel>test</apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText id="i1"/>
        <apex:outputLabel>test</apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText id="i2"/>
        <apex:outputLabel>test</apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText id="i3"/>
    </apex:panelGrid>
```